# How do I run migrations for a specific environment in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up a new app with laravel (Laravel 4), and having some issues setting up the database via migrations.

I made a migration file with:

```
artisan migrate:make --table="jobs" --create jobs
```

Which created a file in database/migrations as expected, I made some mods to this, and went to fire it up using

```
artisan migrate --env=local
```

But I'm getting the reply of `"Nothing to migrate"`

If I try run without `--env=local`, it uses the database.php in the config folder (not in the local / staging / production folder) which we don't want to use, as it won't be environment specific.

My first thought was OK, maybe I need to put the env flag on the `migrate:make` call, so I tried that, but got an error saying it couldn't create the migration file. Then I thought it doesn't make sense to make env based migrations anyway... they should be created generic, and simply run on a per env basis, so in the end, all environments are using the same migration scripts.

So I'm a bit stuck now on where to go to from here

Comment: Depending on Laravel version, see this bug: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12944#issuecomment-214751735

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to specify the environment before the migrate command.

```
artisan --env=local migrate
```

Running `artisan help` shows you the format in which commands are to follow.

```
artisan help

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]
```

Comment: sadly, this had no affect... still getting the `Nothing to migrate` message

Comment: Well, according to the help that's how you specify the options. Take a look at `artisan help` and you'll see it's in the format of `[options] command [arguments]`. My advice now is to make sure your environments are all setup correctly. I just checked, and it works fine for me. So you're missing something else.

Comment: Unfortunately this is totally wrong (at least for Laravel versions I'm familiar with, such as 5.2+). You may have even called the wrong help file. `php artisan help migrate` says "Usage:  `migrate [options]`" and gives options examples such as `--database[=DATABASE]` and `--env[=ENV]`.

Comment: You should add options after artisan command. For example, I want to drop database and start migration from beginning in my testing environment : `php artisan migrate:fresh --env=testing`. Tested on Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out a solution to run `migrate` for different databases. Basically, the command `artisan migrate --env=local` doesn't work. But we can define a new connection string in `config\database.php`. For example:

```
<?php
   'mysql_testing' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_TESTING_HOST'),
        'database'  => env('DB_TESTING_DATABASE'),
        'username'  => env('DB_TESTING_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('DB_TESTING_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => 'prefix_',
    ],
```

And specify the `--database` when we run `artisan migrate` like this:

```
php artisan migrate --database=mysql_testing
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Resolved.

Solution was simply to edit the local/database.php (or production/database.php etc), making sure that the migrations path variable is pointing to the location that `migrate:make` is creating the migration files, just change

```
'application' => __DIR__.'/../database/migrations',
```

to

```
'application' => DIR.'/../../database/migrations',
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify a migration after running it, you first need to rollback the migration.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Keep running that until the migration you've changed is rolled back. Alternatively, you can reset your entire schema with

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

But you will then need to call your migrations like normal to bring them up to date.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Finally you can reset and then migrate by calling

```
php artisan rebuild
```

Also note that it is generally bad practice to modify your migrations after they have been made, unless you literally just made it. Once it is deployed you should not modify it, and instead create a new migration file.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I somehow missed the Laravel 4 indicator. Most of these commands still work I believe, but you may need to adjust.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "made some mods" I just meant I opened the migration file that was just generated, and added in my migration code. I wasn't editing an already run migration. This is the first ever migration for this project

Comment: it is also possible to tear down and rebuild migrations in one commando using  
    php artisan migrate:refresh